# Why doesn't QR decomposition work correctly? (Lapacke, complex case)

Tags: c, linear-algebra, lapacke, qr-decomposition

I use Lapacke. I am trying to do QR decomposition in C for complex data. For this I write the function (based on Haatschii code [How to get the Q from the QR factorization output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29395461/how-to-get-the-q-from-the-qr-factorization-output)):

```
// Q - input: matrix that we expand / output: Q matrix
// R - output: R matrix
// rows - input: number of rows of Q
// columns - input: number of columns of Q
// rows >= columns condition is always met
void QR(lapack_complex_double * Q, lapack_complex_double * R, size_t rows, size_t columns){
    size_t i;
    lapack_complex_double* tau = malloc(columns*sizeof(lapack_complex_double));
    LAPACKE_zgeqrf(LAPACK_ROW_MAJOR, (int) rows, (int) columns, Q, (int) columns, tau); // returns the Q, R in a packed format
    // Copy the upper triangular Matrix R (columns x columns).
    for(i = 0; i < columns; ++i)
        memcpy(R+i*columns+i, Q+i*columns+i, (columns-i)*sizeof(lapack_complex_double));
    LAPACKE_zungqr(LAPACK_ROW_MAJOR, (int) rows, (int) columns, (int) columns, Q, (int) columns, tau); // returns the Q
    free(tau);
}
```

It is worth noting that the author of Alireza also had problems with the function [znugqr](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-3.1.1-html/zungqr.f.html), but however he switched to the function [zunmqr](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-3.1.1-html/zunmqr.f.html) and it seems that happiness has come ([LAPACK QR factorization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45545436/lapack-qr-factorization)). I believe that my problem is also related to `LAPACKE_zungqr` since the matrix R is the same as other methods and therefore `LAPACKE_zgeqrf` works successfully.

But in the end, comparing the similar result (QR decompostion) with Mathematica (`QRDecomposition` function) and Python (`numpy.linalg.qr` function), I see that the matrix Q is different, while the matrix R is the same.

input matrix, for simplicity 5×5:

```
1 + 3j  6 + 8j    11 + 13j  16 + 18j  21 + 23j  
2 + 4j  7 + 9j    12 + 14j  17 + 19j  22 + 24j  
3 + 5j  8 + 10j   13 + 15j  18 + 20j  23 + 25j  
4 + 6j  9 + 11j   14 + 16j  19 + 21j  24 + 26j  
5 + 7j  10 + 12j  15 + 17j  20 + 22j  25 + 27j
```

Output Q matrix (from my C code):
first 3 columns:

```
-0.07254 - 0.21764j    -0.61558 - 0.41039j     0.519770 - 0.06712j
-0.14509 - 0.29019j    -0.35909 - 0.25649j    -0.59817 + 0.211099j
-0.21764 - 0.36273j    -0.10259 - 0.10259j     0.035755 - 0.18619j
-0.29019 - 0.43528j     0.153896 + 0.051298j  -0.35605 + 0.007600j
-0.36273 - 0.50783j     0.410391 + 0.205195j   0.398709 + 0.034623j
```

last 2 columns:

```
-0.12316 - 0.06327j    -0.11940 + 0.303152j
 0.221078 + 0.491045j   0.084589 - 0.02148j
-0.06231 - 0.31146j     0.119483 - 0.80553j
-0.04594 - 0.59711j    -0.01512 + 0.462905j
 0.010343 + 0.480803j  -0.06954 + 0.060958j
```

Output Q matrix (from Python code):

```
-0.11670 - 0.06185j    -0.13105 + 0.301181j
 0.223111 + 0.487988j   0.096454 - 0.02009j
-0.08117 - 0.30874j     0.138515 - 0.80184j
-0.04015 - 0.59906j    -0.04217 + 0.459232j
 0.014923 + 0.481676j  -0.06174 + 0.061519j
```

(Here I am listing only the last 2 columns of this matrix. The first 3 columns are the same).

I calculated the maximum and average difference across the columns in these matrices. The conclusion is this: the first three columns differ at the level of `10^-11`, and the difference between the last two is `10^-3`, `10^-2`, respectively (the difference is visible to the naked eye).

With an increase in the size of the matrix, an increase in the difference is observed and, as a rule, the first 2-3 columns coincide well.

Maybe someone can help me?

Comment: By matrix P you mean the matrix R? can you show the example matrix that you are factorizing?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I have edited the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input matrix A is 5x5 but it has rank 2. The first two columns are linearly independent, while the last three columns of A are linear combinations of the first two.

For a QR factorization, this means that there is not unicity for the last three columns of Q. An QR factorization implementation  (e.g., LAPACK, numpy, etc. ) can return any three columns that are (1) mutually orthonormal and (2) in A^(perp), and that is a correct answer. There are many correct answers! `The` solution is not unique.

If you want to check the Q and R returned by LAPACK, (or any QR factorization implementation for the matter,) you can (1) compute Q'*Q and check that you get the 5x5 identity matrix, (please use BLAS HERK function to do so) and (2) compute Q'*A and check that you have the 5x5 upper triangular matrix R (as returned by QR). In your case you should see that the last 3 rows of R are all zeros, which indicates that the last three columns of A are linear combinations of the first two. To compute Q'*A, you can use BLAS GEMM.

I took your input A and your output Q from LAPACK and I checked for you that Q'*Q is identity and Q'*R is upper triangular with last three rows being fully zeros. So the Q output from LAPACK looks good to me. Yes, this Q is different from what is returned by another implementation and this is entirely possible.

In general we check the quality of a QR factorization by checking that: (1) || A - QR || / || A || is small, (2) || I - Q^T Q || is small, and R is upper triangular. (Take any norm that is easy to compute.)

Checking that two codes return the same output is not a good idea. Since there is not unicity of the output Q and R for two reasons: (1) when A is rank deficient, see the example that you give for example; (2) for any j, any column scaling with a complex number of modulus 1 for the j-th column of Q is possible as long as you scale the j-th row of R accordingly. This changes the Q and R factors but there are still valid Q and R factors.

In addition, assume that you force all diagonal elements of R to be real nonnegative, (by rescaling columns of Q and columns of R appropriately,) and that A is full rank, then you would expect unicity of Q and R. However checking that the pair (Q,R) is close to another one is related to the condition number of computing Q and R for a QR factorization and so you can see pairs that are far apart (forward error), even though they have a good backward error quality.

Comment: Thanks for such a complete answer. While not all points are clear to me, but I'll think about it.

Comment: Indeed, the columns of matrix A are linearly dependent and it has rank 2.